# Operator '>=' incompatible with operand types 'String' and 'Object'

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, entity-framework

I want to create search using linq, I have User table in SQL with two `nvarchar`columns FName and LName and a PK of Id and other columns.

**aspx**:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="search" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                            ontextchanged="search_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>    <br />      
  <asp:ListBox ID="found" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="300px" 
                               AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="LinqUserSearch" DataTextField="Users" 
                               DataValueField="Id">
  </asp:ListBox>   
  <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqUserSearch" runat="server" 
                               ContextTypeName="Zhotel.User" EntityTypeName="" GroupBy="Id" 
                               OrderBy="FName, LName" OrderGroupsBy="key" 
                               Select="new (key as Id, it as Users)" TableName="Users" 
                               Where="FName &gt;= @FName &amp;&amp; LName &gt;= @LName">
        <WhereParameters>
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="search" Name="FName" PropertyName="Text" 
                                       Type="String" />
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="search" Name="LName" PropertyName="Text" 
                                       Type="String" />
  </WhereParameters>
  </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

but in runtime the above code gives me this error.

```
     Operator '>=' incompatible with operand types 'String' and 'Object'
```

I use EF and ASP.NET 4.

Comment: Maybe you have a character escaping problem? (from the DB or even the literals)

Comment: @d'alar'cop I'm a little beginner can you explain more?

Comment: OK. You see how you have some text surrounded with "" (double-quotes)? - sometimes the contents held within need to be 'escaped' since some characters have special meanings - e.g. \n = new-line character. So usually '\' (backslash) needs to be escaped - also double quotes themselves will need to be escaped - usually like \" or "" depending on what language you are using.

Comment: @d'alar'cop thank,I use EF ; I don't know how can I escaped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here to get you started:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1654093.aspx/1

The problem is most likely character escaping issues.

Cheers.